# Cannot commit when use mysqli_multi_query with multiple queries

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I'm trying to commit a mysql multi query, but I can't...

When the mysqli_multi_query "query" has multiple queries cannot commit it. But, when the mysqli_multi_query "query" has an unique query, it is committed correctly. In both cases the execution is OK.

For example:

```
// No commits
$query = "insert into table(id) values (3); insert into table(id) values (4); insert into table (id) values (5);";
$connection = getConnection( ... );
mysqli_multi_query( $connection, $query );
mysqli_commit( $connection );
```

This code commits:

```
// This will commits
$query = "insert into table(id) values (3)";
$connection = getConnection( ... );
mysqli_multi_query( $connection, $query );
mysqli_commit( $connection );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to issue multiple queries for this, one `INSERT` query can contain many rows of values to insert at once. It's also much faster than issuing multiple separate queries.

```
INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (3), (4), (5)
```

Then you can use `mysql_query`/`mysqli_query` instead of the rarely used multi query stuff.

Comment: Yes but is a multi_query function, multi_query is multiple queries in one CALL.